# Compare two columns in google sheets and check if there is a close match

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a query that can search a data range for a close match to a search item

For example the search range might be:

Smith, Carole Ann
Weiser, Barbara
etc

So if I try to query "smith, Carole" or "Weiser, Barbara A" to get a match from the list, my query doesn't work

So far I tried this:

`=QUERY('list'!A2:A, "SELECT * WHERE A like '"& A1 &"'")`

but it doesn't return anything, also tried:

`=QUERY('list'!A2:A, "SELECT * WHERE A contains '"& A1 &"'")`

But it still doesn't work.

here is a sample sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110spyVRj4za4a3Wypqic1Sz9wtTpnSAa1YhvRzZDDbk/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: I updated the question with a sheet, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110spyVRj4za4a3Wypqic1Sz9wtTpnSAa1YhvRzZDDbk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"CONTAINS" will only return the value when the whole substring is present in the cell, as you have written an extra letter 'A' at the end of search string, it will throw an error.

You can try this as an optimized solution:

```
=if(iserror(QUERY(A2:A3, "SELECT * WHERE A contains '"&B2&"'")),QUERY(A2:A3, "SELECT * WHERE A contains '"&INDEX(split(B2," "),1)&"'"),QUERY(A2:A3, "SELECT * WHERE A contains '"&B2&"'"))
```

First it will try to match whole search string but if it throws an error than it will split the search string with space and using 1st keyword it will perform the search and return the row(s).